# Getting Longitude and Latitude using Google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

How do i get longitude longitude of my current phone location using Google maps v2?

I use this method to zoom on my device place:

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

Now how do i get the coordinates?

I know this method to get an area:

```
        double left = vr.latLngBounds.southwest.longitude;
        double top = vr.latLngBounds.northeast.latitude; ...
```

Comment: check this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045754/how-to-get-current-location-on-google-maps-using-map-view

Comment: Cant it be done using Google Maps? to stay efficient

Comment: (-1!!!) Its getting really hard to ask here without getting -1 - At least say why??

Comment: If you have seen the link explains about Google Maps using mapView. I just noticed you have additional question!

Comment: I hope this link help you.
[How to mark the Latitude,Longitude in Google Map ?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032297/how-to-mark-the-latitude-longitude-in-google-map?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the center Lat and Lng values from google maps via this code

```
LatLng latLng = map.getCameraPosition().target;
double lat = latLng.latitude;
double lng = latLng.longitude;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps API location  has listeners, for example:

```
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new 

GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
@Override

public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    mMarker = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
    if(gMap != null){
        gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
    }
}
```

};

and then set the listener for the map:

gMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);

This will get called when the map first finds the location.
try this code.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
private boolean gps_enabled = false;
private boolean network_enabled = false;
private Location location;
private void getMyCurrentLocation() {
    Double MyLat = null, MyLong = null;
    String CityName = "";
    String StateName = "";
    String CountryName = "";
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();

    try {
        gps_enabled = locManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    try {
        network_enabled = locManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    // don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
    // if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
    // return false;

    if (gps_enabled) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, locListener);

    }

    if (gps_enabled) {
        location = locManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    }

    if (network_enabled && location == null) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                0, 0, locListener);

    }

    if (network_enabled && location == null) {
        location = locManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    }

    if (location != null) {

        MyLat = location.getLatitude();
        MyLong = location.getLongitude();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                MyLat, MyLong), 15));

    } else {
        Location loc = getLastKnownLocation(this);
        if (loc != null) {

            MyLat = loc.getLatitude();
            MyLong = loc.getLongitude();

        }
    }
    locManager.removeUpdates(locListener); // removes the periodic updates




}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}

public static Location getLastKnownLocation(Context context) {
    Location location = null;
    LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService("location");
    List list = locationmanager.getAllProviders();
    boolean i = false;
    Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
    do {
        if (!iterator.hasNext())
            break;
        String s = (String) iterator.next();
        if (i != false && !locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(s))
            continue;
        Location location1 = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(s);
        if (location1 == null)
            continue;
        if (location != null) {
            float f = location.getAccuracy();
            float f1 = location1.getAccuracy();
            if (f >= f1) {
                long l = location1.getTime();
                long l1 = location.getTime();
                if (l - l1 <= 600000L)
                    continue;
            }
        }
        location = location1;
        i = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(s);
    } while (true);
    return location;
}
```